# Consumer not reading record from kafka avro serialized topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api

I have been trying write a consumer which read from a kafka topic which been created by confluent kafka jdbc connector.

1. jdbc connector read from sqlite database table name DATA_RECORD.
2. schema for the sqlite table is

   ```
   CREATE TABLE DATA_RECORD (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, RECORD BLOB);
   ```
3. Created avro schema file and generated java source code using avro tool. schema mentioned below

   ```
   { "type": "record",   "name": "DataRecord",   "fields": [
   {"name": "ID", "type": "long"},
   {"name": "RECORD", "type": "string"}    ] }
   ```
4. Then created consumer application which not polling data. consumer java program below

   ```
   package com.fedo.kafka.data.transform;
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Properties;
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

   public class DataTransformer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String topicName    = "data-topic";
       String groupName    = "data-group";

       Properties props    = new Properties();
       props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
       props.put("group.id", groupName);
       props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
       props.put("value.deserializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer");
       props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
       props.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");

       KafkaConsumer<String, DataRecord> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

       consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicName));

       System.out.println("Record polling started.....");
       try {
           while (true){
               ConsumerRecords<String, DataRecord> records = consumer.poll(100);
               for (ConsumerRecord<String, DataRecord> record : records){
                   System.out.println("Key = " + record.key());
                   System.out.println("Val = " + record.value());
               }
           }
       }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally{
           consumer.close();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
5. consumer always not returning any record after each poll.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you able to consume the topic from using bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh? Also check the api version and confirm the ConsumerRecords record value type.

Comment: How do you run the jdbc connector?

Comment: @Yamada Thanks. there was api version miss match in maven build.

Comment: Late comment: A version difference above 0.9 shouldn't determine whether or not you get data from Kafka